# View not updating when it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, dom

Disclaimer, I am an angular noob.

So what I have been trying to do for the past few hours is toggle the authentication in my service with the click of a button which should show the user information or a sign in image depending on if the authentication is true. It displays the correct information when the page loads but will not re-update the view when I click the button. Just for fun, I added a input field that is bound to the user information username to see if the binding was working. I am able to update the username live as expected but I noticed a weird result. If I toggle the authentication button nothing changes but the view will update when I try to update the username via the input box. The change is being made to the authentacation, but just not being reflected for some reason.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var app = angular.module("appMain", []);

app.service("userInformation", [function() {
    this.authentacation = true;
    this.username = "user";
    this.balance = "10.00";
    this.avatar = "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/81/81322ac9812dad58e9525a010c76bcf4e585d820.jpg";

    this.toggleAuthentacation = function() {
        this.authentacation = !this.authentacation;
        console.log(this.authentacation);
    };

}]);

app.controller("headerController", ["$scope", "userInformation", function($scope, userInformation) {
    $scope.userInformation = userInformation;
    console.log($scope.userInformation);


    document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
      userInformation.authentacation = ! userInformation.authentacation;
      $scope.userInformation = userInformation;
      console.log($scope.userInformation);
    });

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="appMain">

    <header ng-controller="headerController">
      <img id="logo" src="/img/logo.png">
      <div id="userInfo" ng-show="userInformation.authentacation">
          <ul>
              <li>Hello {{userInformation.username}}!</li>
              <li>Balance: ${{userInformation.balance}}</li>
              <li><img id="avatar" src="{{userInformation.avatar}}" /></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="userInfo" ng-hide="userInformation.authentacation">
          <ul>
              <li><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_01.png"></li>
          </ul>
      </div>

        <button id="btn1">Button1</button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="userInformation.username">
    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your button isn't doing anything now. It's just a plain ol' button. You'd want to wire it to your `toggleAuthentacation` function using `ng-click`

Comment: The button is in fact updating the value and is being assigned a role in the headerController. I have checked that it is working with console.log

Comment: @Ladmerc Upon further investigation this was the problem! I added a function to the controller which I called with ng-click which updated the view instantly. You are a life saver!

Comment: Yes, after my edit it now works. Always check the console for internal Angular errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events handlers need to be integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. 
The [`ng-click` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) automatically does that.

Angular modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and Angular execution context. Only operations which are applied in Angular execution context will benefit from Angular data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc

> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [angularjs.org](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/img/guide/concepts-runtime.png))</sub>
>
> [--AngularJS Developer Guide v1.1 - Concepts - Runtime](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide/concepts#runtime)

Comment: Tried both changes and they yield the same result as before.

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying it though, this is something that commonly affects large applications when scoping becomes an issue (JavaScript scopes, not Angular scopes)... I'll mark this answer as a community-wiki item as it isn't particularly useful for you issue.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I solved the issue by not binding the function to the button via document.getElementById but instead making a function inside of the controller which I bind using ng-click in the html.

```js
app.controller("headerController", ["$scope", "userInformation", function($scope, userInformation) {
    $scope.userInformation = userInformation;
    console.log($scope.userInformation);


    $scope.toggleAuthentacation = function() {
      userInformation.authentacation = ! userInformation.authentacation;
      $scope.userInformation = userInformation;
      console.log($scope.userInformation);
    };

}]);
```

```html
<button id="btn1" ng-click="toggleAuthentacation()">Button1</button>
```

Comment: Angular modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and Angular execution context. Only operations which are applied in Angular execution context will benefit from Angular data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc